# Authentication with Dropbox Api V2

Tags: android, dropbox

I am searching for days now and still don't know how to do this. Maybe you can help me.

I want to integrate Dropbox into my App and use the [Dropbox API V2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java). But the way to authenticate the App with the Acc of the user isn't described. To use the API I use the Maven-dependency.

There is an [example for android](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android) but there is nothing about an authentication. Is here anybody who already did this? But with the V2, because V1 is deprecated.

Comment: There's a post here with information and links showing how to hook up the app authorization flow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870585/how-do-i-authenticate-in-dropboxapi-v2-for-android

Comment: I know how to authenticate the user account, so i don't think it is a duplicate. But I found this https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Deleted-files-metadata/td-p/213170. So it isn't possible at the moment, because there is no flag like for the other MetaData objects.